# read user input string with space between quotes in C and keep the quotes

Tags: c, string, character-class

e.g `"task 1"`

What character class can I use in order to keep the quotes?

Comment: Were you thinking of using `scanf` to read such a string from the user?

Comment: Do you mean "How can I read user input between two sets of quotes?" as in the input `"a" "b c"` would result in two different strings, `"a"` and `"b c"`?

Comment: You either mistagged your post `character-class`, or should probably explicitly say which regex library you are using.  It's also pretty unclear what you're asking.  A little sample code demonstrating your problem would be helpful.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to keep the quotes?  Usually it's desired to have the quotes protect the space within the string, but *not* themselves be part of the string.

Comment: I'm thinking of using scanf to read user input, that's why I asked for the character class. As for attempts, I have this \"%[^\"]\" which doesn't keep the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do what your intending,  You need to use `scanf` and have a predetermined amount of characters you want between the string. This will construct a string the keeps literal quotes and a null character at the end, so the string can be reprinted.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int charsToRead = 6;
    char inputString[9];
    char* inputPointer = inputString + 1;
    inputString[0] = '"';
    inputString[7] = '"';
    inputString[8] = '\0';
    printf("type something with quotes\n");
    scanf("\"%6c\"", inputPointer);
    printf("the captured string is %s", inputString);
    return 0;
}
```

to take in the string "task 1", you need 6 characters to be read between the quotes, which is reflected above.